How to construct class proportion confidence interval for an LLM classifier with known bias and precision and recall?
Let's say I have a dataset, $D$,  with known ground truth labels. I nonetheless use a few-shot LLM classifier on this dataset to predict $k$ classes for each label.
From the LLM results, I get precision-recall scores for every $k$ class. I also get a bias amount for the proportion of each label as the difference of the predicted proportion vs. the ground truth. I know how accurate the model is at predicting labels.
I now plan to predict labels on a new dataset, where I don't know the ground truth. I want to quantify the uncertainty of total number of labels in each category based on the past performance of the LLM.
Normally, I might use the bootstrap to simply re-sample and re-fit a deterministic model in a loop and take the empirical distribution of the predictions to get the confidence intervals of the prediction. However, we cannot do that because the LLM calls are too expensive.
My thinking is that instead we should:

Determine the bias of the classifier for each $k$ class by subtracting the empirical estimated class proportion $\frac{TP_k}{N}$ from the known proportion $p_k$.
Determine a confidence interval for the empirical class estimate $\frac{TP_k}{N}$ using standard wald normal-approximation binomial methods and simply shift these intervals by the bias amount.

However, I'm not sure this is valid. It doesn't feel valid because the standard error is not invariant to the value of $p_k$.
